# Icons are not showing in the UITab bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar

Icons are not showing in the UITab bar instead some rectangles are showing. What could be the problem?

My code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) {
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"poolmate.png"];
}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized your `tabBarItem`. Try this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.tabBarItem = [self tabBarItem];
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"poolmate.png"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: You should post some more code so others can help you too. For instance, post where your `self.tabBarItem` is initialized or assigned.

Comment: have you used allocation of viewcontroller  with this            `MapViewController *viewControllerOne = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];`

Comment: then only your image setting will work or you can set during tabbarcontroller creation with viewcontroller instance